# What to inherit from when I want to create a new fstream?

Tags: c++, inheritance, filestream

I want to define a new type of `filestream` in C++. What should I inherit from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inherit from `basic_filebuf`, or `basic_streambuf` if you're writing the I/O parts from scratch. You might also want a class derived from `basic_[i/o]fstream`, but that is strictly optional, for convenience. If templating is not required, drop the `basic_` and inherit from the classes, not the templates.

The `*stream` classes all dispatch I/O through a polymorphic pointer which you can get and set using the `rdbuf()` method. So unless/until you implement the convenience class, you can test by instantiating `std::iostream` and calling `rdbuf` with your pointer.

It is very useful to have a copy of the Standard handy, to work through the requirements for the derived class. Your main functionality will be in the virtual functions `overflow` and `underflow`.